# Why it's not possible to access variables from parent/outer scope in anonymous functions on PHP?

Tags: php, function, anonymous-function

Here's my anonymous function:

```
<td><?=call_user_func(function($x) { if ($x == 1) { echo $produto->retornaMedida($dadosProdutos[$t]->medida_id); } else if ($x == 2) { echo "N/A"; } }, $dadosProdutos[$t]->produto_id)?></td>
```

It works perfectly well if I don't use something "out of scope" inside the scope of the conditions, like this:

```
<td><?=call_user_func(function($x) { if ($x == 1) { echo "Whatever"; } else if ($x == 2) { echo "N/A"; } }, $dadosProdutos[$t]->produto_id)?></td>
```

But when I use `$dadosProdutos`, for example, I get a:

```
[24-Dec-2015 03:47:58 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dadosProdutos in G:\Insanity\Web\xampp\htdocs\sisconbr-old\site\modulos\pedido\minhas-cotacoes.php on line 269
```

And $dadosProdutos is not "undefined" when used out of the anonymous function:

```
<td><?=$produto->retornaMedida($dadosProdutos[$t]->medida_id)?></td>
```

Interestingly, I have no problems when I pass the outside variable as an argument to the anonymous function. [I think this is what they mean with "capturing an out-of-scope variable" on C++'s lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Tried looking at the [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) keyword?

Comment: Passing as a parameter or making use of the `use` clause, this is how you can control the variables scope with PHP closures. That is just [standard PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the variable you need with **use**.

```
$world = 'world';

$func = function() use ($world) {
    echo 'hello ' . $world;
};

$func();  
// hello world
```